# spark.read.options(header=True, delimiter="|").csv("mycsv") taking too much time for 3 rows in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create DataFrame from csv file in PySpark but it's taking too much time for a specific file

```
step1 = datetime.now()
file_path = r'csv/'
csv_data = glob.glob(file_path+'*mycsv*.txt') or glob.glob(file_path='*test*.txt')
print('-------------------------------',csv_data[0])
print(F"\nStep-1 | {(datetime.now() - step1).total_seconds()}\n")

step2 = datetime.now()
df = spark.read.options(header=True, delimiter="|").csv(csv_data[0]) # here it's taking time
print(F"\nStep-2 | {(datetime.now() - step2).total_seconds()}\n")

step3 = datetime.now()
df = subset_df(csv_header, df)
print(F"\nStep-3 | {(datetime.now() - step3).total_seconds()}\n")
```

this the output of given code :

```
Step-1 | 0.000465

Step-2 | 3.708599

Step-3 | 0.38075
```

in given output Step-2 taking 3 seconds or sometime it take 5 second and inside my csv file I've only 4 rows including header any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will say that's correct.
step1 is only for getting target file names.

but the step2 is really the first time that action method(read) to kick up spark application run. as you know, for submit a spark job ,need start up a diver firstly, then register AM, apply resources, dispatch tasks for executing and so on, there are a lot of complicate progresses before we get first job run.
so i think it's normal for spent several seconds to kick up a spark job as the first time.

for step3 maybe is some transform on df, once the spark application started will no need that complicate, just need dispatch new job to run couldn't spent too much time.

Comment: Hello @RandChen Thanks for your reply but I'm starting or creating my dirver at the top of my code like this ```spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.driver.memory", "15g").getOrCreate()```

Comment: Does this line start spark driver or it just create for us.

Comment: Is there any suggestion to improve speed of code execution

Comment: @AnkitTiwari for spark driver, that code just create a SparkSession instance for submit job but not really start it. for the speed of code execution, it will not obviously improve as i think, but if it's a truly big volume data use case, data process time could be hours or days, spend several seconds to start a  job is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, @RandChen for your information.